# Configuration in IOS settingsview

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

Many IOS-applications have the possibility to edit your personal settings, like username and password, at the settingswindow of your device.
I've looked all around the web, but it's hard to find something about how to do this.
Can somebody here tell me how to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's called a Settings Bundle. Read [Apple's doc](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/Preferences/Preferences.html).